# How can I get all my instance in heap ,nonheap and stack memory?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, stack-memory

I connected my jvm with JMXConnector in java.(https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/how_to_retrieve_remote_jvm)
I get RuntimeMXBean instance and learn a lot of things about jvm.
For example;

```
   System.out.println("Target VM is: "+remoteRuntime.getName());
    System.out.println("Started since: "+remoteRuntime.getUptime());
    System.out.println("With Classpath: "+remoteRuntime.getClassPath());
    System.out.println("And args: "+remoteRuntime.getInputArguments());
```

And than I use ManagementFactory.I get memory,thread,classes

```
 MemoryMXBean memory=ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
      ThreadMXBean threads=ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
      RuntimeMXBean runtime=ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
      ClassLoadingMXBean     classes=ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
```

But I want to learn my all instance info in jvm memory(heap,nonheap,stack).
For example;I create 10 class.I have 10 instance.I want to do analysis of my jvm memory.(For example;How many instance created in heap,nonheap or which instance is old generation,young generation?)
I can get heap memory size so I think ,i can get all instance in heap memory.
http://www.javased.com/?api=java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean